# Input stream into c program

Tags: c

I have a file with the following values:

```
12,23
2 90
```

I have a linked list structure that has a function to add values to it:

```
add_value(int x).
```

My end goal is to direct the file to my cprog and have the values (ints) all added to my structure.

```
file | cprog
```

But I can't figure out how to read each digit, add it to my linked list, and ultimately move onto the next digit and add that too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x, status;

while((status=scanf("%d", &x))!=EOF){
    if(status == 1)
        add_value(x);
    else
        fgetc(stdin);//drop one character
}
```

Comment: Hi BLUEPIXY, is there a way to check if the current character is a letter or number? and add it to the list???? some things in my file are not ints.. thanks

Comment: `"%d"` accept the `int` then  `else` not accept. you _have a linked list structure that has a function to add values to it_

Answer (score 1):

After opening the file you could use:

```
fscanf(inputStream, "%d%d", &var1, &var2); // example
```

Which puts the read integers in the corresponding variables. Then you can take those variables and add them to your list.

Comment: That example code will only read in the first integers in the file. You would have to move to the other integers to keep getting more. If you knew exactly how many to move you could do something like `inputStream + 2`.

Comment: The only thing is what if I don't know how many ints are in the file?

Comment: You must check the return value.

Comment: I suggest converting one number at a time. Then you can just keep calling `fscanf` until it returns `!= 1`.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest. use a for loop to get an integer and add it to the list until there aren't anymore, i.e. EOF.